# D3 exit transition: animation translate to left before remove

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to have text that is generated from d3 exit with a transition animation. It supposed to fly slowly over to the left and fade out at the same time. However, you will notice from the following snippet that the text is immediately updated and the exit animation never seems to be called.

Can't get the css applied for some reason, the text that reads: "Next Event" is clickable, click on it to see the transition.

```js
var width = 200;
var height = 100;
var margins = {left:20, right:20, top:0, bottom:0 };

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width+margins.left+margins.right)
    .attr('height', height+margins.top+margins.bottom);

var data = [
    {'Date':'May-24', 'Event':'Event 1'},
    {'Date':'Jun-30', 'Event':'Event 2'}
];


var dateG = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate('+margins.left+','+(margins.top+40)+')')
    .attr('class', 'uiText');

function displayData(data) {

var dateText = dateG
    .selectAll('text')
    .data([data]);

dateText
    .enter()
    .append('text');

dateText
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .text(function(d) { return d.Date; });

dateText
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr('x', -50)
    .attr('opacity', 0)
    .remove();

}

displayData(data[0]);

d3.select('#button').on('click', function(d) {
    displayData(data[1]);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class='button' id='button'>Next Event</div>
<body>
```

I have also tried calling `remove()` separately, like so:

```
dateText
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr('x', -50)
    .attr('opacity', 0);

dateText
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .remove();
```

I have also tried throwing in a `delay()` before `remove()`, but none of the above made a difference.

Lastly, I tried adding an extra `.select('text')` after `.exit()`, but to no avail.

**Question:** Can I have an exit animation as per my code above with a few tweaks, or is there a fundamental flaw in my implementation? What do I need to tweak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use a key function...

```
.data([data], function(d) {
    return d.Event
});
```

... the data will be bound by *index*.

Besides that, change `attr` to `style`.

Here is the code with these changes:

```js
var width = 200;
var height = 100;
var margins = {
  left: 20,
  right: 20,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0
};

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margins.left + margins.right)
  .attr('height', height + margins.top + margins.bottom);

var data = [{
    'Date': 'May-24',
    'Event': 'Event 1'
  },
  {
    'Date': 'Jun-30',
    'Event': 'Event 2'
  }
];


var dateG = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + (margins.top + 40) + ')')
  .attr('class', 'uiText');

function displayData(data) {

  var dateText = dateG
    .selectAll('text')
    .data([data], function(d) {
      return d.Event
    });

  dateText
    .enter()
    .append('text');

  dateText
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.Date;
    });

  dateText
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr('x', -50)
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .remove();

}

displayData(data[0]);

d3.select('#button').on('click', function(d) {
  displayData(data[1]);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class='button' id='button'>Next Event</div>

<body>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great! Strangely when I tried nearly the same logic for the `enter()` animation, the `x` attribute didn't change. I had `.attr('x', 100)` before the `.transition()`, then `.attr('x', 0)` after the `.transition()`. I have been tinkering with it ever since your answer. It's nothing too major though, you don't need to edit your answer or anything. I just thought I'd let you know in case you had a hunch.

Comment: That's because you're not removing the `attr("x"` in the update selection. By the way, any reason for using D3 v3?

Comment: You mean I need to add an `.update()` section? I think I'm intimidated by v4. I got used to the overt chaining style of v3, like: `d3.svg.axis()` I think v4 is `d3.svgAxis()` or something.

Comment: You already have an update selection. You have to remove the `attr("x"` there. And there is no `d3.svgAxis()`!